# Using the Buildfire Custom Plugin and Deep Linking to Link to Internal Features

Tags: buildfire

I would like to use the Buildfire Custom Plugin to create a home page for my app.  From there I need to link to external websites and internal plugins using Deep Linking.

When I target deep links I get a mixed content error:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://app.buildfire.com/#/pluginControl/01331574-e5fc-4d9e-b226-ecd69029358b/01331574-e5fc-4d9e-b226-ecd69029358b-1549414186849/New%20Home/3000dd44-17a3-464c-a438-d31843d7cbe4/false?headerId=5c5a2f2b236aa005d368b399' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'app0070be://plugin/169d5e94-6c5e-4769-b4ca-a7d0175985e7-1528925513379'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Here is the code I'm using:

```js
var search = document.getElementById("search");
search.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("Search");  // I am seeing this in the console prior to the error.
    document.location('app0070be://plugin/ba4139dd-09c6-4121-aa4a-c72570af07fc-1490476490653');
});
```

Is there a way to make this secure?  Is there a better / different approach I should consider?

Comment: Are you using the deprecated "custom plugin" or you are creating a custom plugin using the BuildFire SDK?

Comment: I'm using the "custom plugin" found in Buildfire's list of features.  Had no idea it was deprecated though.

Comment: Best to sign up on https://dev.buildfire.com for a developer account. Its free. You can build everything you need there and there is great documentation and videos to help you get started. https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki

Comment: You can also see all BuildFire's open source plugins in github https://github.com/BuildFire . This can help with example code or even code you can copy since its all under an MIT license. To address specifically how to navigate to another feature/plugin read this https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Navigation

Comment: Also worth while to see how Folder Plugins are made in BuildFire's open source github repos. This will help you understand how to find the plugin you want as well as how to navigate to it.  ref https://github.com/BuildFire?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=folder&type=&language=